# Express $abab^3$ in standard form for the $Dic_6$?

Tags: group-theory

For the group

$Dic_6 = < a, b| a^4 = e, a^2 = b^6, aba^3 b= e >$,

express $abab^3$ in standard form.

I've had a try below, but I'm guessing and it's probably wrong.

$abab^3 = abaa$, because $a^2 = b^6$, therefore $a = b^3$

$abaa = aba^2$

Since $aba^3 b = e,$

$aba^2 = a^{-1} b^{-1} = a^3 b^5$.

If someone could steer me in the right direction I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: How do I superscript my exponents?  I don't seem to have managed it in the question.

Comment: Use math mode; put math between dollar ($) signs. For more details see the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). There also seems to be a typo in your title.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!

Comment: For exponents like in $a^{-1}$, place the exponent in brackets `{..}`.

Comment: Note that $a^2=b^6$ does not imply that $a=b^3$.

Comment: I thought that step was a stretch, but I'm not sure what relation I should use instead.  Did the final step make sense at least or am i completely off?

Comment: The final step mostly makes sense; how do you get $a^{-1}b^{-1}=a^3b^5$? It is true that $a^{-1}=a^3$ because you are given that $a^4=e$, but you are not given that $b^6=e$...

Comment: I used that because it needs to be have a power from 0 to 5, but I can see why that is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:**

> Write $abab^3=(aba^3b)(b^{-1}a^{-2}b^3)$.

**Hint 2:**

> Prove that $a^{-2}=b^{-6}$.

Comment: I'll give it a go, will report back in a min!

Comment: I got $b^8$, but I'm not sure how to get that into the right form, if it is correct.

Comment: That's right! I'm not sure what the 'right' form is for you. But recall that $a^2=b^6$, does this help?

Comment: Could I change it to $b^8 = b^6b^2 = a^2b^2$?

Comment: That's what I had in mind, yes. Is that the right form for you?

Comment: Yeah, that's it!  The second factor in hint 1 with the negative exponents, did you decide on that with a similiar logic to the final step of my original attempt or was it something else?

Comment: I just figured you'd need to use the fact that $aba^3b=e$ at some point. Taking this factor out necessarily leaves you with the second factor.

Comment: P.S. if your question is answered, please accept this answer so the question doesn't end up in the 'unanswered' queue.

Comment: To the (top) left of every answer there are up and down arrows (for up- and downvoting) with a total score inbetween, underneath there is a checkmark to accept an answer. And welcome to the site :)

Comment: Done!  Thanks again, you've been really helpful.